# Markov Models simple introduction

Tags: reference-request, stochastic-processes, markov-chains

We're studying Markov models (still at the basis: transitory states, periodic states, etc..) but the professor isn't very good at teaching and I feel I'm getting lost soon.

I'd love to have a simple introductory "Markov Models for dummies" text where to refer for definitions and simple examples. Can you suggest one please?

Comment: This is the first time I ever wanted to add a sixth tag: (reference-request) :-)

Comment: I'd personally boil it down to just (markov-chains) and (reference-request).  The others are auxiliary or overly broad, and of course everyone question would like a response that increases intuition.  I mentally reserve that tag for when that the questioner understands a specific result "on paper", but is missing the intuition behind it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not in any way "for dummies", but you might look at http://www.statslab.cam.ac.uk/~james/Markov/

Comment: I thought exactly of the same book :) but then I decided that there are not enough modeling examples. Not enough for the OP, the book I like.

Comment: It's not very easy to read, anything a little more "coincise" ?

Comment: Which do you want, concise or easy to read?  In mathematics those attributes tend to be negatively correlated.

Comment: ok, let's choose "easy to read"

Comment: You might try http://math.colgate.edu/~wweckesser/math312Spring05/handouts/MarkovChains.pdf

Comment: Thank you, this looks "easy-enough" to read (as easy as a markov model document may be)